# How do I make this python code work properly to open chrome?

Tags: python-3.x

currently having this problem with my code and would appreciate if somebody could help:

```
import bs4
import requests
import sys
import webbrowser

res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' + ''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
linkElements = soup.select('.r a')
linkToOpen = min(5, len(linkElements))

for i in range(linkToOpen):
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com' + linkElements[i].get('href'))
```

[This is the ouput im facing and no chrome is opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx027.png)

Comment: linkToOpen is empty

Comment: what do I update in linkToOpen ?

Comment: I don't know what your goal is. Describe in more detail

Comment: the program's execution will prompt google chrome to open and text (any text entered in CLI "  will be searched

Comment: @SergeyK thank you for your help, but replacing soup. select('.r a') with soup.select('div#main > div > div > div > a') solved the problem

Comment: then you only need one line of code - `webbrowser.open(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={sys.argv[1]}')`